# Возникает ошибка при обращении к методу в объекте cell[i][j]

Tags: java

Я пишу шашки. Создал класс *Cell.java*, там храню координаты.
Хочу по ним вывести массив квадратов. Возникает ошибка, когда обращаюсь в методе `paint()` к методу в объекте `cell[i][j]` для получения координат.

Что я сделал не так?

```
public class Test1 extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static void createMainFrame()
    {
        JPanel panel = new Test1();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Graphics app");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        mainFrame.setContentPane(panel);
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    Cell cell[][] = new Cell[8][8];

    public void initCells()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {      
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
               cell[i][j] = new Cell(i * 30, j * 30);
            }
        }
    }

    void Print(int i, int j) // это для того чтобы убедиться, что я объекты успешно созданы и значения в них есть
    {
        int tempx = cell[i][j].ReturnX();
        int tempy = cell[i][j].ReturnY();
        System.out.println("координаты X " + tempx + " Y " + tempy);
    }

    void PaintWithCords(Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {      
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                g.drawRect(x, y, 30, 30); 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {      
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                int tempx = cell[i][j].ReturnX(); - ошибка
                int tempy = cell[i][j].ReturnY();
                PaintWithCords(g, tempx, tempy );
            }
        }
        PaintWithCords(g, 10, 10); 
        PaintWithCords(g, 20, 70);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test1 t1 = new Test1();
        t1.initCells();
        t1.Print(1, 2);
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                createMainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*Cell.java*:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int x, y; // потом сделай private 
    boolean isEmpty = true;

    Cell()
    {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    Cell(int a, int b)
    {
       this.x = a;
       this.y = b;
    }

    void SetCoordinates(int a, int b)
    {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    } 

    public int ReturnX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int ReturnY()
    {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну ошибка же должна сопровождаться каким либо логом

Comment: Какая возникает ошибка ?

Comment: Без знания о том, какая у вас ошибка - никак. Логи приложите.

Comment: @s_klepcha `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` уж тогда.

Comment: Мой магический шар настаивает на `NPE`

Comment: вангуется `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ваш магический шар видит, что `panel` и `t1` - разные объекты, только вот одном из которых инициализирован массив клеток?

Comment: iCheater Retaehci кто вас учил название методов с большой буквы писать

Comment: @s_klepcha похоже на то, что к этому коду прикладывали руки минимум два человека, один из которых "больше по C#". Либо у автора нет стандартов для наименования методов, расстановки пробелов и прочего.

Comment: Кстати, в приведённом листинге мне не найти где вызывается `paint()`. @Regent, , да, вижу)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб этж swing

Comment: Ошибка возникает при первом заходе в цикл и попадании на строчку: int tempx = cell[i][j].ReturnX(); - ошибка ?

Answer (score 4):

У вас, скорее всего, **NPE** при попытке обращения к пустому элементу массива.

1. В `main()` вы создаёте экземпляр **Test1** в коем массив заполняете методом `initCells()`.
2. Потом же в методе `createMainFrame()` вы создаёте ещё один объект **Test1** и для него массив не заполняете.

Засим, судя по всему, в методе `createMainFrame()` вам надо добавить строку

```
panel.initCells()
```